# Can't link external CSS to HTML

Tags: html, css

I currently studying HTML Css and my problem is my external css wont link to the HTML, using Sublime and Notepad++. But when i use regular notedpad it works. Just wanted to know how to solve it, its kinda convenient using those text editors.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can link a CSS file like so (in head):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

With `style.css` being the name of the CSS file, assuming
it is in the same folder as the HTML file. If it were a directory back,
your would use `../style.css`, and in a folder, `myfolder/style.css`.

So your HTML file would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the full path. Is it online or in your local machine?
Example for online:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/ >
```

Example for machine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="C:\Users\eduardo.pimenta\Documents\Visual Studio\Workspace\play\css.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add link Tag in head within which add the path of css file in href.

For example, if css is the folder name and styles is the css file inside it, then:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```